# Is there any ndiswrapper alternative for audio drivers

Tags: ndiswrapper

**Asus X205A** have a working audio driver in Windows. I was wondering Is there any **ndiswrapper** alternative for audio drivers? so that i can wrap the windows driver and use that in ubuntu.

Life without sound is terrible..

Comment: Why the down vote? pls explain. so that i can make the change

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such thing.

- [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Asus/X205TA) shows no driver support for it ...

> Audio
>
> The built-in card is a Realtek RT5648 (unverified). At this moment there isn't any driver for this card (as of Linux Kernel 4.1.3) :

- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=95681
- http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.alsa.devel/138822

But work is done to get one done. The gmane list has some good info.

Comment: is there any wrappers available to load windows driver?

Comment: see the 1st sentence in the answer: no.

Comment: reverse engineering possible?